# Returning true if sum of squared is greater than sum of cubed

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean, reduce

slight noob question here.

I'm trying to return true for all the squared sum of arrays for 'a' which are greater than 'b' on a CodeWars challenge. This is what I have so far:

```
function arrayMadness(a, b) {
  
  a = a.reduce((ele, ele2) => {
    return (ele ** 2) + (ele2 ** 2);
});
  b = b.reduce((ele, ele2) => {
    return (ele *ele *ele) + (ele2 *ele2 * ele2);
});

  if (a > b) {
   return true;
   } else return false;
}
```

However, I'm still failing on some of the tests. Could anyone help me out as to where I've gone wrong?

Many thanks in advance! :)

P.S. Here is the challenge: https://www.codewars.com/kata/56ff6a70e1a63ccdfa0001b1/train/javascript

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation of the code? It is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Code answer is here

```
function arrayMadness(a, b) {
  sumA = a.reduce((acc, currentEl) => {
    return acc + (currentEl ** 2);
  }, 0);
  sumB = b.reduce((acc, currentEl2) => {
    return acc + Math.pow(currentEl2, 3);
  }, 0);

  return (sumA > sumB) ? true : false;
}
```

Explain: reduce take 4 parameters where also you can define **initialValue** as extra parameter as you see in my code after comma '0', where reduce includes the first index of array to calculate.
Reference: [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)